# Unkown Swap Encoding

Tags: obfuscation, encryption, binary-diagnosis

I'm trying to figure out this encoding in malware.. All I have are the static strings..

I was able to figure one out so there is plaintext on one:

```
e-snAetgrU$
```

translates to

```
$User-Agent
```

Here are some other strings from the same malware if it helps. I've tried 16/32 byte swaps and tried looking at the delta between the plaintext character index and the encoded one..

```
rdcTNIOemr$
MyNonASUo
uCoDL
MaNOza$
.eiCeShdPH$
ETSOHD$
RRNIootP$
```

Comment: A code snippet would help. Do you know where the "swap decoding" function is? Can you edit your question and add the code for that?

Comment: The function is VB from a malicious macro. I was unable to decompile source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

googling for e-snAetgrU yields the VBA Macros
just copy paste the macros into a VBA module in word/excel/
insert a few Msgbox() and you can decrypt all the strings

the unobfuscation is as follows

```
obf_str       = "e-snAetgrU"
obf_str_len   = len(obf-str)   == 10
redherr       = 1
i = 0

d(69, 43, obf_str)

rand = arg1  == 69

REPEAT:

Char_Choice_num = ( arg1 - (obf_str_len * (arg1 \ obf_str_len) )) ==
(69,52 - (10 * (69,52\10 == 6,5) == 60,50) ==) {9,2,5,8}

unobf_str[i++] = obf_str[Char_Choice_num+redherr] == obf_str[10,3,6,9] = 'U,s,e,r'

rand = Char_Choice_num+arg2  ==  52,45,48,51

goto REPEAT Until Len (obfxx) == len(unobfyy)
```

[image]